# Cálculo entre inputs em tabela com criação de linhas dinâmicas

Tags: javascript

Estou montando uma tabela onde as linhas são criadas dinâmicas, nessas linhas estou fazendo uma multiplicação do campo `Qtde` * `VlrUnitVista` e jogando o valor no campo `VlrTotalVista` e está funcionando bem, na primeira linha, nas linhas seguintes os cálculos não estão sendo feitos, como adaptar o código que tenho, código esse pego do site do `William Bruno`, para que os cálculos possam ser realizados também nas linhas a serem inseridas?
Uma outra dificuldade que encontrei foi que também preciso fazer o cálculo de `Qtde` * `VlrUnitPrazo` e jogar o valor no campo `VlrTotalPrazo`, fiz alguns testes alterando o nome de algumas funções e até duplicando as mesmas, mas sem chances.

O form que tenho está assim:

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="post" >
     <div id="mensagem" class=""></div>

        <div class="table-responsive">
           <table width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="products-table">
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <th colspan="6" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                     <th colspan="4" class="actions">Unidade</th>
                     <th class="actions">&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <th colspan="2" class="actions">A vista</th>
                     <th colspan="2" class="actions">A prazo</th>
                     <th class="actions">&nbsp;</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <th width="12%">Produto</th>
                    <th width="12%">Embalagem</th>
                    <th width="12%">Concorrência</th>
                    <th width="10%">Fonte</th>
                    <th width="10%">Frete</th>
                    <th width="10%">Qtde</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="actions">Unitário</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="actions">Total</th>
                    <th width="18%" class="actions">Ações</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width="12%"><input id="Produto" name="Produto[]" type="text" size="10" ></td>                        
                    <td width="12%"><input id="Embalagem" name="Embalagem[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="12%"><input id="Concorrencia" name="Concorrencia[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input id="Fonte" name="Fonte[]" type="text" value="Produtor" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input id="Frete" name="Frete[]" type="text" value="CIF" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input id="Qtde" name="Qtde[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="11%"><input id="VlrUnitVista" name="VlrUnitVista[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="6%"><input  id="VlrTotalVista" name="VlrTotalVista[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="8%"><input  id="VlrUnitPrazo[]" name="VlrUnitPrazo[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="8%"><input  id="VlrTotalPrazo[]"  name="VlrTotalPrazo[]" type="text" size="10"></td>                        
                    <td class="actions">
                       <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="11" style="text-align: left;">
                       <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button">Adicionar Linha</button>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tfoot>
           </table>
        </div>
```

A criação das linhas dinâmicas da tabela estão assim:

```js
(function($) {
   
    RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
      var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');
   
      tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
        tr.remove(); 
      }); 
   
      return false;
    };
    
    AddTableRow = function() {
        
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        
  cols += '<td><input type="text" id="Produto" name="Produto[]" value="" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="Embalagem" name="Embalagem[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="Concorrencia" name="Concorrencia[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="Fonte" name="Fonte[]" size="10" value="Produtor"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="Frete" name="Frete[]" size="10" value="CIF"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" id="Qtde" name="Qtde[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="VlrUnitVista" name="VlrUnitVista[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="VlrTotalVista" name="VlrTotalVista[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="VlrUnitPrazo" name="VlrUnitPrazo[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="VlrTotalPrazo" name="VlrTotalPrazo[]" size="10"></td>';
          
        
        cols += '<td class="actions">';
        cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
        cols += '</td>';
        
        newRow.append(cols);
        
        $("#products-table").append(newRow);
      
        return false;
    };
    
   })(jQuery);
```

E os cálculos estão sendo feitos usando isso:

```js
 function id(el) {
   return document.getElementById(el);
 }

 function total( Qtde, VlrUnitVista ) {
   return parseFloat(Qtde.replace(',', '.'), 10) * parseFloat(VlrUnitVista.replace(',', '.'), 10);
 }

 window.onload = function() {
   id('Qtde').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var result = total( this.value , id('VlrUnitVista').value );
  id('VlrTotalVista').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
   });

   id('VlrUnitVista').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  var result = total( id('Qtde').value , this.value );
  id('VlrTotalVista').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
   });
 }
 


 String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
   var v = this;

   if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
   }

   v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
   v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
   v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

   return v;
 };
```

Estou postando a imagem do meu form, se ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar `id` nos campos, você irá duplicar os mesmos `ids` ao criar linhas dinâmicas. Além de ser errado (um `id` deve ser único na página) você não conseguirá pegar os valores dos campos. É preciso trocar todos os `ids` dos campos por `class`.

Outro ponto é: já que está usando jQuery, não faz sentido misturar JavaScript puro usando `window.onload` e `addEventListener`. Inclua os eventos `keyup` dentro da função `(function($){`.

O que eu fiz foi converter os eventos `addEventListener` em formato jQuery que irá capturar os valores nas linhas dinâmicas. Além disso, foi preciso criar um outro evento para os valores da coluna "A prazo":

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".Qtde", function(){
   var result = total( $(this).val() , $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrUnitVista").val() );
   if(!isNaN(result)) $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrTotalVista").val(String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney());
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".VlrUnitVista", function(){
   var result = total( $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qtde").val() , $(this).val() );
   if(!isNaN(result)) $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrTotalVista").val(String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney());
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".VlrUnitPrazo", function(){
   var result = total( $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qtde").val() , $(this).val() );
   if(!isNaN(result)) $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrTotalPrazo").val(String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney());
});
```

Então, o código ficou assim:

```js
(function($) {
   
    RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
      var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');
   
      tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
        tr.remove(); 
      }); 
   
      return false;
    };
    
    AddTableRow = function() {
        
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        
  cols += '<td><input type="text" class="Produto" name="Produto[]" value="" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="Embalagem" name="Embalagem[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="Concorrencia" name="Concorrencia[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="Fonte" name="Fonte[]" size="10" value="Produtor"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="Frete" name="Frete[]" size="10" value="CIF"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" class="Qtde" name="Qtde[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="VlrUnitVista" name="VlrUnitVista[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="VlrTotalVista" name="VlrTotalVista[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="VlrUnitPrazo" name="VlrUnitPrazo[]" size="10"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="VlrTotalPrazo" name="VlrTotalPrazo[]" size="10"></td>';
          
        
        cols += '<td class="actions">';
        cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
        cols += '</td>';
        
        newRow.append(cols);
        
        $("#products-table").append(newRow);
      
        return false;
    };

   $(document).on("keyup", ".Qtde", function(){
  var result = total( $(this).val() , $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrUnitVista").val() );
  if(!isNaN(result)) $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrTotalVista").val(String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney());
   });

   $(document).on("keyup", ".VlrUnitVista", function(){
  var result = total( $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qtde").val() , $(this).val() );
  if(!isNaN(result)) $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrTotalVista").val(String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney());
   });

   $(document).on("keyup", ".VlrUnitPrazo", function(){
  var result = total( $(this).closest("tr").find(".Qtde").val() , $(this).val() );
  if(!isNaN(result)) $(this).closest("tr").find(".VlrTotalPrazo").val(String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney());
   });


})(jQuery);
   
   function id(el) {
   return document.getElementById(el);
 }

 function total( Qtde, VlrUnitVista ) {
   return parseFloat(Qtde.replace(',', '.'), 10) * parseFloat(VlrUnitVista.replace(',', '.'), 10);
 }


 String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
   var v = this;

   if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
   }

   v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
   v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
   v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

   return v;
 };
```

```css
table { 
   table-layout: fixed; 
   border-collapse: collapse; 
} 

th { 
   border: 1px solid #000; 
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 0.8em; 
   background-color: #009fef; 
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
} 

td { 
   border: 1px solid #000; 
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 0.8em; 
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
} 

.centro { 
   text-align: center; 
} 

.cinzaClaro { 
   background-color: #CACACA; 
} 

.cinzaEscuro { 
   background-color: #EBEBEB; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="" method="post" >
     <div id="mensagem" class=""></div>

        <div class="table-responsive">
           <table width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="products-table">
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <th colspan="6" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                     <th colspan="4" class="actions">Unidade</th>
                     <th class="actions">&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <th colspan="2" class="actions">A vista</th>
                     <th colspan="2" class="actions">A prazo</th>
                     <th class="actions">&nbsp;</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <th width="12%">Produto</th>
                    <th width="12%">Embalagem</th>
                    <th width="12%">Concorrência</th>
                    <th width="10%">Fonte</th>
                    <th width="10%">Frete</th>
                    <th width="10%">Qtde</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="actions">Unitário</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="actions">Total</th>
                    <th width="18%" class="actions">Ações</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width="12%"><input class="Produto" name="Produto[]" type="text" size="10" ></td>                        
                    <td width="12%"><input class="Embalagem" name="Embalagem[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="12%"><input class="Concorrencia" name="Concorrencia[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input class="Fonte" name="Fonte[]" type="text" value="Produtor" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input class="Frete" name="Frete[]" type="text" value="CIF" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input class="Qtde" name="Qtde[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="11%"><input class="VlrUnitVista" name="VlrUnitVista[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="6%"><input  class="VlrTotalVista" name="VlrTotalVista[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="8%"><input  class="VlrUnitPrazo" name="VlrUnitPrazo[]" type="text" size="10"></td>
                    <td width="8%"><input  class="VlrTotalPrazo"  name="VlrTotalPrazo[]" type="text" size="10"></td>                        
                    <td class="actions">
                       <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="11" style="text-align: left;">
                       <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button">Adicionar Linha</button>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tfoot>
           </table>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Fantástico @dvd, muitíssimo obrigado pelo excelente código.